# QWidget based class resize doesn't work in mdi mode

Tags: qt, qwidget, qmdiarea

I'm trying to make a subwindow for my mdiform.
I use the code below:

```
pygApp *app1 = new pygApp;
app1->resize(400,400);
area->addSubWindow(app1);
```

where pygApp is a QWidget based class:

```
class pygApp : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    pygApp();
};
```

but the result is:
[image]

as you see, the subwindow is minimized for no reason. I used setGeometry too, but nothing changed. what should I do?

Comment: what is the method `addSubWindow` doing??

Comment: Have you tried `app1->showNormal();` or `app1->showMaximized();` after you add it as a subwindow?

Comment: You might also want to test these methods on its parent `app1->parentWidget()`

Comment: I had a similar problem... `resize()` was working everywhere but not in the constructor. My solution was to set a minimum size `setMinimumSize(400,400)`. I didnt need the seMinimumSize after I added some widgets to my window. It auto resized to handle the widgets.